# MongoDB - forcing stored value to uppercase and searching

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

in SQL world I could do something to the effect of:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE UPPER(name) = UPPER('Smith');
```

and this would match a search for "Smith", "SMITH", "SmiTH", etc... because it forces the query and the value to be the same case.

However, MongoDB doesn't seem to have this capability without using a RegEx, which won't use indexes and would be slow for a large amount of data.

Is there a way to convert a stored value to a particular case before doing a search against it in MongoDB?

I've come across the $toUpper aggregate, but I can't figure out how that would be used in this particular case.

If there's not way to convert stored values before searching, is it possible to have MongoDB convert a value when it's created in Mongo?  So when I add a document to the collection it would force the "name" attribute to a particular case?  Something like a callback in the Rails world.

It looks like there's the ability to create stored JS for MongoDB as well, similar to a Stored Procedure.  Would that be a feasible solution as well?

Mostly looking for a push in the right direction; I can figure out the particular code once I know what I'm looking for, but so far I'm not even sure if my desired functionality is doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to normalize your data before storing them. There is no support for performing normalization as part of a query at runtime.

Comment: That's what I was partly afraid of.  I'm using the MongoImporter tool to load some of the data, so I don't really have a convenient means of normalizing the data before it gets ingested into MongoDB.  Looks like I may have to have another job that does some middle-work before finally loading.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do is probably to save both a case-normalized (i.e. all-uppercase) and display version of the field you want to search by. Suppose you are storing users and want to do a case-insensitive search on last name. You might store:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    first_name: "Dan",
    last_name: "Crosta",
    last_name_upper: "CROSTA"
}
```

You can then create an index on `last_name_upper`, and query like:

```
> db.users.find({last_name_upper: "CROSTA"})
```

Comment: That would be a better solution, however I'm using the MongoImporter and don't really have access to manipulate the data like this when I load it in bulk.  Items created in the app itself can do this, but not the initial bulk import.  This is a good solution, it just won't work for my particular case.